# Long question titles not consistently shortened in user profile popup

Tags: bug, user-interface, profile-popup

Long question titles are usually shortened in the user profile popup. This is not applied consistently, as shown in the screenshot below.

The first question title is not shortened, but truncated by the element border (last character looks like a lowercase L, but actually is a truncated `b`). The *same question title* is shortened in the line below it.

> [image: Screenshot of user card dropdown]